# PHP - Multiple SQL queries to a HTML table using search results

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have found similar topics, but many of the results use mysqli_multi_query which is something that I wish to avoid due to future implementations of user-generated queries.

Currently I am achieving my desired result using the following PHP, but I have a feeling there is a more effective method which I am missing. I am also afraid of concurrent queries and the possibility of such an involved process occupying connections. Though the userload at any one time should not be > 20.

Here is the code, any critique or insight appreciated! (I am still learning PHP as I go, therefore my code is likely shit in that regard!):

Table schema (which needs work as well - developing best structure as I go essentially):

```
CREATE TABLE `EAM`(
    `EAM_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `EAM_IPADDR` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    `EAM_PORT` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `EAM_STATE` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `ACTIVE`(
    `EAM_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    `ACTIVE_STATUS` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `ACTIVE_TIME` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (EAM_ID) REFERENCES EAM(EAM_ID));

CREATE TABLE `MAP_IMG` (
  `MAP_IMG_BLDG` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `MAP_IMG_ROOM` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `MAP_IMG_X` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAP_IMG_Y` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAP_IMG_ROOM_STATUS` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOTCLEAR');

CREATE TABLE `LOCATION`(
    `LOCATION_ROOM` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `LOCATION_BLDG` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `EAM_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    `LOCATION_COMMENT` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (EAM_ID) REFERENCES EAM(EAM_ID));
```

---

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT EAM_ID FROM LOCATION WHERE LOCATION_BLDG = 'LQ1'"; //TODO: Eventually make this 'LQ1' a variable for page selected.
$dbQueryResult = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $dbQuery) OR DIE("Bad Query: $dbQuery");

    echo "<table class='table table-striped'><thead>"; 
    echo "<tr><th>BUILDING</th>";
    echo "<th>ROOM NUMBER</th>";
    echo "<th>ROOM STATUS</th>";
    echo "<th>LAST UPDATE</th>";
    echo "<th>EAM IP ADDRESS</th>";
    echo "<th>EAM PORT</th></tr></thead>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbQueryResult)) {

      $eamID = $row['EAM_ID']; //Assign EAM_ID from initial query to $eamID for use throughout subsequent queries.


      $dbq2 = "SELECT LOCATION_BLDG, LOCATION_ROOM FROM LOCATION WHERE EAM_ID = $eamID";
      $dbqr2 = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $dbq2) OR DIE("Bad Query: $dbq2");

      while($r2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbqr2)) {

        echo "<tr><td>{$r2['LOCATION_BLDG']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$r2['LOCATION_ROOM']}</td>";

      }

      $dbq2 = "SELECT ACTIVE_STATUS, ACTIVE_TIME FROM ACTIVE WHERE EAM_ID = $eamID";
      $dbqr2 = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $dbq2) OR DIE("Bad Query: $dbq2");

       while($r2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbqr2)) {

         echo "<td>{$r2['ACTIVE_STATUS']}</td>";
         echo "<td>{$r2['ACTIVE_TIME']}</td>";

       }

      $dbq2 = "SELECT EAM_IPADDR, EAM_PORT FROM EAM WHERE EAM_ID = $eamID";
      $dbqr2 = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $dbq2) OR DIE("Bad Query: $dbq2");

       while($r2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbqr2)) {

        echo "<td>{$r2['EAM_IPADDR']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$r2['EAM_PORT']}</td></tr>";

       }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use one query that joins the tables? Edit your question and add the schemas of the three tables.

Comment: Might be a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: To complement @SloanThrasher, have a look at LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN and related "table joiners"

Comment: Also, when you use a variable to replace the location id, use a parameterized query and bind() to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the queries in a loop to get related data, use one query at the top to return the data.

```
SELECT 
    a.`EAM_ID`,
    a.`LOCATION_BLDG`,
    a.`LOCATION_ROOM`,
    b.`ACTIVE_STATUS`,
    b.`ACTIVE_TIME`
FROM `LOCATION` a
LEFT JOIN `ACTIVE` b
ON a.`EAM_ID` = b.`EAM_ID`
LEFT JOIN `EAM` c
ON a.`EAM_ID` = c.`EAM_ID`
WHERE a.`LOCATION_BLDG` = 'LQ1'
```

Comment: It appears each query inside the loop is expected to return data, otherwise the user's HTML table would be broken, so INNER JOINs are possible here.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the reply and solution. That is far better than numerous queries in loop. Also to your comment above, once I use variable in this query, I will be sure to use bind() as well!

Comment: If you only want rows that have matching rows in the other two tables, remove the **LEFT** on the JOINS. If it works, be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: @ethan would it be possible to use mysqli_store_result here and then access data from this through fetch_assoc or fetch_row? Maybe store them as objects to access them?

Comment: You can fetch all of the rows from the query into an associated array, then loop through them to output the rows in your HTML table. take a look at [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: @billybutthead You can fetch data from the query however you like.  My comment was merely to suggest your query is a good candidate for INNER JOINs rather than LEFT JOINs.  An INNER JOIN is much more performant than a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Good copy on INNER rather than left.